# Unable to understand how FindFit function works.

Tags: fitting

```
ks = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
   800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
   70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
aa1 = {3.14172, 3.15756, 3.17331, 3.2041, 3.23399, 3.26304, 3.29131, 
   3.48223, 3.74135, 4.13211, 4.66617, 5.04019, 5.3278, 5.56008, 
   5.75347, 6.05965, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 
   6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 6.28314, 
   6.28314, 6.28314};
aa2 = {9.42478, 9.42537, 9.42596, 9.42716, 9.42836, 9.42955, 9.43075, 
   9.43974, 9.45479, 9.48511, 9.54657, 9.60893, 9.67202, 9.73563, 
   9.79957, 9.92774, 10.0553, 10.6536, 11.5696, 11.9059, 12.5663, 
   12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 
   12.5663, 12.5663};
aa3 = {12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 
   12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 
   12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.5663, 12.9037, 
   13.3636, 13.6161, 13.8784, 14.0112, 14.1813, 14.2487, 14.388, 
   14.4031, 14.4032};
p1 = ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{ks[[i]], aa1[[i]]}, {i, Length[ks]}], 
   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{ks[[i]], aa2[[i]]}, {i, Length[ks]}], 
   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];
p3 = ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{ks[[i]], aa3[[i]]}, {i, Length[ks]}], 
   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];
Show[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> All]
lst = N[Table[{Log10[ks[[i]]], aa1}, {i, Length[ks]}]]
model = a E^(b (x - c))/(E^(b (x - c)) + 1) + d
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {a, b, c, d}, x]
Plot[model /. ff, {x, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {3, 6.5}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

I have three sets of data aa1,aa2,aa3, I am trying to fit an equation for this data, data looks like a sigmoid function. So I have used a fit model which resembles the sigmoid function. Later I used the FindFit function to extract the unknown coefficients. when I plotted the fitted model I am getting a straight line. What mistake I am doing. same thing is happening for aa2 and aa3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your definition of `lst`, I believe you forgot to add the `Part` specification on `aa1`.

```
lst = N[Table[{Log10[ks[[i]]], aa1[[i]]}, {i, Length[ks]}]]
```

or

```
lst = Thread@{Log10[ks], aa1} // N
```

Which then yields the final plot

[image]

Comment: Extremely sorry, It's my mistake, I did not give attention to missing aa1[[i]]. Thanks for your time.